# how to hide system folder of sdcard in android?

Tags: android, listview, gridview

hi i want make simple file explorer which can display all folder of sdcard using listview and only display image file using gridview.i do all of this thing very well.Display in screen shot.but after this i handle the all folder structure of sdcard.also revers process will be handle successfully.but problem is there
when i click on the system folder like `.android_secure` ,`secure` ,`asec` then display Null pointer Exception.but i handle this if folder is empty then display Message folder is empty.
so what i can do now?how to handle this problem.
first i want hide this folder means does not display in listview. but can`t success.
please give me the way.

[image]

**First Error Image**

[image]

Now I add Next Point in this that i want to delete specific folder.so i use **`file.delete()`** but if the folder is not empty then what to do?
i also want delete this folder with all contain it`s possible with android2.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use File, 
try

```
File file;
if(file.isfolder && file.list[] != null && file.isreadable()){ // check read,write access 
imageView.setVisible(Visible)
}else{
// hide your list item data
}
```

or first check adapter data and then put it into adapter.

```
File files
// ... check files
Adapter adapter = new Adapter(files)
setListAdapter(adapter)
```

Comment: Thanks Dear i use isReadable(); but if you use api level 2.2 then this method can`t support so use instead of canRead() and canWrite()